# How to estimate java permgen size required?

Tags: java, permgen

How can I estimate the permgen space requirement for a java application? I am not looking to minimize the permgen space requirement for the code that I write, but given the size of the jars of my own code and that of the 3rd parties, how do I get a reasonable estimate of the permgen size that will be required for running the program?

Comment: There is no way to do that without knowing what does your code do. This kind of estimate is not done by the amount of JARs your application have, but what it consumes regarding memory.

Comment: Could you please let us know that what are those factors, those impact it most?

Comment: Why do you think that you need to do that?

Comment: Obligatory question: do you use Java 8? If you do, you should not even care since the permgen in Java 8 is gone

Comment: If you are using Java 8, there is no more PermGem space

Comment: fge,Alexey Zavyalov- No i dont use Java 8.
@Jorge- I hit this problem when i try to use some 3rd party jars in the application. So, giving a MaxpermGen and profiling once is the only way to estimate?

Comment: The answer provided by @malaguna is exactly what you should do. Test your application within different scenarios to see how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

PermGen space is reserved for long-term objects, those objects who has survived young garbage collections.

It is quite difficult to know how much space do you need. I think the best you can do is to use JConsole or VisualVM (or whatever) to profile your applications under several possible scenarios.

This way you can get an idea on how much permgen space do you need, but don't calculate an average, use the maximum.

Anyway, I won't use the maximum value, instead I will increase it in any percent, at least 15-20%. But keep in mind, this can be dangerous if you don't estimate over nice scenarios ...